# Linux - Servidor SFTP

Tags: linux, debian, debian-9, sftp, vsftp

Estoy montando un servidor local para hacer "pruebas" he montado un s.o debian con nginx y apache.

Ahora estoy pensando como montar los accesos via sftp, mi idea es que cada usuario tenga su login.

Ejemplo: usuario1,usuario2....y luego el acceso como root.

Lo que quiero hacer de "peculiar" es que los usuarios solo puedan acceder al directorio de apache, es decir que al entrar por sftp vayan al directorio /var/www/html y que de ese directorio no se puedan mover.

No se si es mejor hacer un grupo con estas opciones o simplemente "restringir" el vsftpd para que todo usuario loggeado acceda solo y exclusivamente a esa carpeta.

```
chroot_local_user = NO
```

Gracias.

Comment: Has pensado en usar jailkit? Esta herramienta te permite "enjaular" a los usuarios en un directorio en concreto, definiendo, entre otras opciones, un PATH determinado, con acceso estrictamente a los comandos que desees

Comment: No lo conocía, le daré un ojo. Gracias!!!